# how to make list of strings from file where this strings are in own line

Tags: text-processing

I have file:

```
xxx.lst
```

with values:

```
111
222
333
```

I just need to make one line with:

```
111 222 333
```

into a variable or standard output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`paste` is probably the best tool for this job:

```
$ paste -sd ' ' file
111 222 333
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't even know this exists, even on AIX :-). Thx.

Comment: @user165435: It works in any POSIX compliant system.

Comment: Nice, I looked it up, `paste` belongs to coreutils package

Comment: @warl0ck: It's POSIX standard, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tr to replace line separator with space, e.g

```
set -f
somevar="$(tr '\n' ' ' < xxx.lst)"
echo $somevar
```

Comment: works of course

Answer (score 0):

Xargs echo and i/o redirection.

```
xargs echo < xxx.lst
```

You don't even need the echo.

```
xargs < xxx.lst
```

Tested on ksh/aix and bash/GNU.

Comment: Note that `xargs` choked on unbalance double quotes line, remove balance double quotes line.

Comment: True! `xargs -0 < xxx.lst` with GNU xargs will work with any unbalanced quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

This also work:

```
set -f; printf '%s ' $(cat infile )
```